# PHP to ASP.NET conversion

Tags: php, asp.net

Does anyone know how to convert the following PHP code to ASP.NET?

```
<?php
$myFile = "includes/status.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, 1);

$status= $theData;

if ( $status == 0) {
    include('includes/bol_down.php');
} 
    elseif ($status == 1){
    include('includes/login_form_up.php');
}

fclose($fh);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably depends a lot on what's being included.  ASP.NET doesn't "include" other code in this manner.

If the code being included is just PHP code, then there's no need for this in ASP.NET.  The compiled assembly has all of the available code from the compilation already available.

If the code being included is actual page output, then it's a different model for how you'd accomplish this.  The closest analogy would be to [conditionally display a user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86.aspx).  Something like this:

```
if (status == 0)
{
  var myControl = (MyControlType)LoadControl("~/MyControl.ascx");
  myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(myControl);
}
else if (status == 1)
{
  var myOtherControl = (MyOtherControlType)LoadControl("~/MyOtherControl.ascx");
  myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(myOtherControl);
}
```

In this case, `myPlaceHolder` is an existing control on the page which exists solely as a, well, placeholder in order to add controls dynamically.  This is because the page life cycle is different in ASP.NET than in PHP.  In PHP the scripts are added in-line, whereas in ASP.NET the user controls are inserted into existing markup structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
int status = theData;

if(status == 0)
{
  Response.WriteFile("includes/bol_down.html");  
}
else if(status == 1)
{
  Response.WriteFile("includes/login_form_up.html");
}
```

I'm assuming `theData` is of type `int` (integer).

Couple things to note. ASP.NET precompiles before deployment which is why you can't dynamically add using `include`. Instead, you have to write the file directly to the output stream (`WriteFile()`). Also, the file you include can't contain ASP.NET server side code. If it does, the code won't be executed, it will simply be displayed to the user. There may be an alternative to what you're trying to achieve. You can read more on dynamically including the file [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306575).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){ 

    include_once "ez_sql_core.php";
    include_once "ez_sql_mysql.php";
    $db = new ezSQL_mysql('db_user','db_password','db_name','db_host'); 

    $song = $db->get_row("SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");

    $artist = $song->artist;
    $songname = $song->title;
    $url = $song->url;
    $separator = '|';
    echo $url.$separator.$artist.$separator.$songname;
} 

?>
```